# PHP IRC bot that reads data returned from a command of the IRC server

Tags: php, sockets, bots, irc

I'm using a IRC bot written in procedural PHP that was originally created by Phil, and now I'm using it for learning purpose. The bot works, it sets the IRC server and joins the channels that were set, it can also handle simple commands and respond something back into the channel. 
But I'm trying to create a command whenever somebody writes "!call wakey wakey it's time to wake up now" then the bot sends a message inside the channel with a list of usernames and the message that was written after "!call" in a newline after posting the list with names.

For example:

Current users in the channel are:
foo
bar
foobar
barfoo

Person A says: !call does anyone know where I can find my teddy-bear?
Bot responds: foo, bar, foobar, barfoo
Bot responds: does anyone know where I can find my teddy-bear?

What is does, is that is will be triggered if "!call" is at the start of a message. Then it will call a function get_data_call which will take the message from the channel and split the !call and the message and the function only returns the message back or returns false. so far it works, I did get the message stored in a variable.

Now what my problem is:

Now I must send a "NAMES " command to the IRC server, which then returns a list of usernames that are currently in the channel that the bot is in. But I can't seem to catch that list, I do see that I get a message back from the server and I've tried to use something like that but I'm sure this not the exact way to do it (otherwise it would work):

```
while (!feof($sock)) 
{
$readCall = fread($sock, 4024);
if ($readCall === true) 
{
while (strpos($readCall, ':irc.rizon.no') !== false) 
{
echo "irc.rizon.no found!";
break;
}
}
else 
{
echo "readCall returns false.";
break;
}
}
```

This doesn't work and will always return false.

The full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/edit.php?i=F2bAdDmS

I hope somebody on this wonderful site can help me with this, I will really appreciate that.

Thank you.
//Xenios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos()` will return a positive integer, or 0, when a match is found. You should try instead using a `!== false` in your condition, because `strpos()` can return 0 if a match is found in the first character.

Comment: @LouisH. Thanks, I just added the bang after the equals. :P

Comment: Thanks for that. I saw that I'm getting server replies (353) and (366) the next is the exact message on my cli screen: readCall returns false.-> :irc.rizon.no 353 bot @ #channel :+bot ~user1 &user2 @user3 -> :irc.rizon.no 366 nl-bot #channel:End of /NAMES list. Should I use strpos() to search for that code in the socket?

Comment: @Xenioz as what you have got is a string then `strpos()` is the right way. It is a fast and lightweight method to find whether a character or text is present in a string or not. If you need more sophisticared matching there are many more functions too.

Comment: I've been experimenting a bit with strpos, but I still dont get the part with usernames of the NAMES command. I've have this code http://pastebin.com/mYErETps I tried to use that inside the code block where I send the NAMES command and just under the code where the data gets read (you can view this code in my main post), but both don't catch the message send from the server, I do get "am.i PRIV" printed on my screen which is part of my hostmask and part of the PRIVMSG cmd send **to** the server, when using the code above inside the if block statement where I send the NAMES command. please help

Comment: @Xenioz first try printing on screen, with `echo` for example, the string that you are fetching from the server. I think you are kind of trying to solve a problem, blind.

Comment: I made it write to a txt file (view here: http://pastebin.com/6z2AmUaK my command output is on line 146) even though it was already outputting data in my cli screen. Also I forgot to say that 353 + 366 is send when joining a channel and that the socket loop reads 512 bytes each iteration. But the data that I've extracted with the code (see my previous comment) doesn't make sense to output "am.i PRIV" because this nowhere to be found bewteen the first 353 and 366 reply codes that I used as start and end for my substr().

Comment: @Xenioz in your code try changing  `if ($readCall === true)` into `if (strlen($readCall))`.

Comment: But I'm not using that code, http://pastebin.com/mYErETps is the piece of code that resulted into "am.i PRIV".

Comment: @Xenioz ah yes, then you should quote the search string in your `strpos()` calls. Change `strpos($cmd, 353)` `to strpos($cmd, '353')` for example.

Comment: Well, it all worked after I moved the 353 checker on the top of the socket loop and call it where I use the NAMES command.