# Python IRC bot that reads data returned from a command of the IRC server

Tags: python, bots, irc, names

I have a similar question to [PHP IRC bot that reads data returned from a command of the IRC server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031760/php-irc-bot-that-reads-data-returned-from-a-command-of-the-irc-server)

I'm using an IRC bot written in Python found widely across the web.

I must send a "NAMES" command to the IRC server, which then returns a list of usernames that are currently in the channel that the bot is in. But I can't seem to catch that list, **NOR** get a message back from the server - the bot receives and prints messages sent by other users, but not by himself nor command outputs.

To print the data I'm using the following:

```
while True:
    data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
    (...)
    print data
```

To send the NAMES command I tried the following:

```
irc.send ( 'NAMES #channel\r\n' )
```

And:

```
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #channel :/names\r\n' )
```

The complete code at pastebin dot com: http://pastebin.com/xjymEjPu

Comment: I suggest you use highlevel IRC library which makes your task much easier: http://python-irclib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just able to see the NAMES list in the script output

```
:botty!~botty@durrrrrrrrr JOIN :#channel
:retribution.sg.as.irchighway.net 353 botty = #channel :botty IlPalazzo-ojiisan @Nibelung 
:retribution.sg.as.irchighway.net 366 botty #channel :End of /NAMES list.
:retribution.sg.as.irchighway.net 353 botty = #channel :botty IlPalazzo-ojiisan @Nibelung 
:retribution.sg.as.irchighway.net 366 botty #channel :End of /NAMES list.
```

It isn't the last thing to pop up though. Perhaps you missed it? It was above a set of global notices that were the last lines to return.

Comment: :) Easy to miss. I was expecting it to pop up at the bottom and only spotted it when telnetting in. It's also worth noting that the NAMES list is there twice, that's because you receive it automagically when you JOIN a channel.